# Apply a Filter on the Response of a Request in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I am trying to get a specific entry of a JSON Array in the Paw-App, but cannot rely on the order.

If I have the response

```
{
 "array":[
   {
     "field1":"A",
     "field2":"B"
   }, {
     "field1":"C",
     "field2":"D"
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to have the Value of field 1("C"), if the value of field2 is "D", no matter the order of the array.

Is there any solution for this using Paw?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. But, we would love to add this in the next release, though. (will push it higher in our todo)

Comment: thanks for pushing it higher

Comment: Is this available now? I've been looking for the same thing, and can't find how to do it.